# Convex Optimization with linear shift of variables

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

In the standard convex optimization problem where the objective is optimized over x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,....,x<sub>n</sub>, does a change of variables to x<sub>1</sub>-a<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>-a<sub>2</sub>.....,x<sub>n</sub>-a<sub>n</sub>change the global optimum?

Would it be right to say the optimal point is achieved at x<sup>*</sup><sub>i</sub> - a<sub>i</sub> , i $\epsilon${1,2,....n} ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO  that's wrong. (answer of second question)

Let assume the original optimal value is $f(x^*)$ , where $f$ is objective function and $x^*$ is optimal solution. Now by changing variable $x \to x-a$, new objective function is $f(x-a)$ so optimal value is still $f(x^*)$. This shows optimal solution is $x^* + a$

Actually the change variable $x \to x -a$ will shift the domain of $f$ (feasible set ) toward **$+a$**.

** EDIT **

The answer of first question is (usually) Yes. Generally input_translation will change optimal solution, but not optimal value.

Comment: You should clarify what is wrong. The OP asked a question (well, two questions).

Comment: I think the body of answer will answer his two questions. But anyway I have Edited it for more clarification.  @copper.hat

Comment: by shift i meant an appropriate sign for 'a' based on direction of shift. So basically the optimum value is unchanged, and the value at which it is optimized shifts accordingly. I found it intuitive in 2D 3D problems. Wanted to confirm in n dimensions. Thanks ! :)